# how to control check box and show on grid kendo ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new on kendo ui. I need your help, please. I need to use checkbox somewhere. My problem is when I edit any record, checkbox which is on popup menu can show status of attribute but grid doesn't show. I want to show attribute of the record show in checkbox on grid.

I try to this sample :http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Templates/grid-with-checkbox-column but It doesn't work for my expected.

Here is my code:

```
                    {
                        field: "isWorking",
                        title: "Çalışıyor",
                        editor: '<input type="checkbox" #= isWorking ? \'checked="checked"\' : "" # class="chkbx" />'
                    },
                    {
                        command: [
                            {
                                name: "edit",
                                text: {
                                    edit: "",
                                    update: "Tamam",
                                    cancel: "İptal"
                                },
                                className: "grid-command-iconfix"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "destroy",
                                text: "",
                                className: "grid-command-iconfix"
                            }
                        ],
                        title: "&nbsp;",
                        width: "120px"
                    }
                ],
                editable: {
                    mode: "popup",
                    window: {
                        title: "Kayıt".i18n()
                    },
                    confirmation: "Silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?".i18n(),
                    confirmDelete: "Yes"
                },
                edit: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    $("#maritalStatus").data("kendoDropDownList");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $("personGrid.k-grid-content").on("change","input.chkbx",function(e){
        var grid = $("#personGrid").data("kendoGrid"),
            dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));

        dataItem.set("isWorking", this.checked);
    });
```

And screenshots of how it works. Please follow the ss.
[image]

[image]

From here this is solution from linke where is given by me up of issue.

Here code is my first work:

```
 {
                        field: "isWorking",
                        title: "Çalışıyor",
                        template: "<input type='checkbox' id='isWorking'/>"
                    },
                    {
                        command: [
                            {
                                name: "edit",
                                text: {
                                    edit: "",
                                    update: "Tamam",
                                    cancel: "İptal"
                                },
                                className: "grid-command-iconfix"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "destroy",
                                text: "",
                                className: "grid-command-iconfix"
                            }
                        ],
                        title: "&nbsp;",
                        width: "120px"
                    }
                ],
                editable: {
                    mode: "popup",
                    window: {
                        title: "Kayıt".i18n()
                    },
                    confirmation: "Silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?".i18n(),
                    confirmDelete: "Yes"
                },
                edit: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    $("#maritalStatus").data("kendoDropDownList");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And here how is work ss. It's show  status on popup edit menu but it doesn't show on grid.
[image]

please could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the checkbox in the template but not its value. It will have always the initial state. Try this template:

```
template: "<input type='checkbox' id='isWorking' # if (isWorking) { # checked=\"checked\" # } # />"
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EfuWI)

Comment: I found this just 2 minutes ago template: "<input name='isWorking' type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: isWorking' #= isWorking ? checked='checked' : '' #/>" and it's solved my issue but it's same what you propose. thank you, I turn green your answer.